# Grails background-thread, Quartz

Tags: grails

I'm developing a football manager website, but I can't figure out how to use properly the background-thread plugin and Quartz plugin (there is no much docs).
My problem is..
I have a Controller of a Match class, with a function that I need to start at some time.
With quartz I have tried to create a job but then I cannot call directly the function (and how many job should I create if I have more match to start?) or I don't know how to do it, and with background-thread I create the service class but then I have no idea how to implement it.
Someone Can help me with this?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

**Solution in this post:**

[grails thread -> hibernateException: No Hibernate session bound to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088259/grails-thread-hibernateexception-no-hibernate-session-bound-to-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times just need to keep tryng :)
With quartz I do like this:

```
class TestJob {

    MatchController match = new MatchController()

    static triggers = {
        /*
         * firstThread runs every minute from 8 to 9:59 on wednsday
         */
        cron name: 'firstThread', cronExpression: "0 0/1 8-9 ? * WED"
        cron name: 'secondThread', cronExpression: "0 0/5 8-9 ? * WED"
        cron name: 'thirdThread', cronExpression: "0 0/10 8-9 ? * WED"
        cron name: 'forthThread', cronExpression: "0 0/15 8-9 ? * WED"
    }

    def group = "MyGroup"

    def execute() {
        /*
         *  execute task
         *  call playMatch from match controller
         */
        println "run thread: "
            + String.format('%tH:%<tM:%<tS.%<tL',System.currentTimeMillis())

        match.playMatch()
    }
}
```

Seems to work.
But still wonder I to use background-thread

Answer (score 1):

Background-thread was designed as a simple plugin to just do as the name suggests - run some code in a background thread.

It doesn't give you a handle to the background thread (that I can recall) so it's just a 'set and forget' type of thing.

Quartz is the right choice for what you want to do. I probably wouldn't have the Job calling the controller though. The logic of 'playing a match' sounds like it should be in a service. You can get your services injected into Job classes the same as you can in controllers.

cheers

Lee

Comment: you're right with service is much better, I didn't think about it, especially when you need to call a function in different controllers.

Comment: The service probably shouldn't be calling functions on the controller.  Controllers are meant to handle different actions from incoming http requests.  If your service "needs" to call a controller action, you may want to look into redesigning that code.  Perhaps pull the code out of the controller and into a new service; then both the controller and any other services can call it.

Comment: now what I'm doing is for example:
League class call on save, a LeagueService with a method that generates all the leauges I need.
Am I doing it right?

Comment: This is my idea how to use quartz
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042492/grails-quartz-thread, but I don't know how to create thread in the service, keep getting ExceptionPrinterJobListener and Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.Thread(fproject.Match)