# Grails service ->java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method serviceMethod() on null object

Tags: grails

I have Class in src/groovy . I want to use my service here . but error occurred "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here ". i try to debug but not able to find . can you please help me that what is my mistake .

```
class ListenerSession implements HttpSessionListener  {
    def transactionService = new TransactionService ()
    public ListenerSession() {
    }
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent){
    }
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
        HttpSession session = sessionEvent.getSession();
        User user=session["user"]
        if(user){
            try{
                java.util.Date date = session['loginDate']
                transactionService.updateUserLastLogin(user,date)
-----}catch (Exception e) {
                println e
    }
```

code in service is:

```
def updateUserLastLogin(User user,Date date){
        try{
            User.withTransaction{
                println "121212"
                user.lastLogin=date
                user.loginDuration=new Date().time - user?.lastLogin?.time
                def x=user.save()
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            println e
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should consider to write your code into a "code block", so that it's better to read... did you add your listener to the `web.xml` file? also, this should give you some advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088259/grails-thread-hibernateexception-no-hibernate-session-bound-to-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails won't inject your service for you in the src/groovy level and just declaring a new instance of `TransactionService` will not give you all the goodies (hence your error).  You need to get your instance form the spring context like so...

```
  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH
  import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes as GA

  class ListenerSession implements HttpSessionListener  {

        public ListenerSession() {
        }
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent){
        }
        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent) {
            HttpSession session = sessionEvent.getSession();
            User user=session["user"]
            if(user){
                try{
                    java.util.Date date = session['loginDate']
                    def ctx = SCH.servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
                    def transactionService = ctx.transactionService
                    transactionService.updateUserLastLogin(user,date)
                 }catch (Exception e) {
                    println e
                 }
             }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't instantiate services with `new`. If they use nearly any piece of Grails framework, that piece won't work - like GORM session in this case.

Here's an exactly your question: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Injecting-Grails-service-into-HttpSessionListener-can-it-be-done-td1379074.html

with Burt's answer:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ServletContextHolder.
  getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
transactionService = (TransactionService) ctx.getBean("transactionService")
```